# Nofollow attribute in Wordpress link embed code?

Tags: embed, nofollow

I am including links to items I've written for clients in a WP post, but want them to be "no follow" to avoid any issues with those same clients.

The links are posted as embed code and I'm not sure how or where to add the rel="nofollow" attribute. The code looks like this:

```
    <figure class="wp-block-embed-wordpress wp-block-embed is-type-wp-embed is-provider"><div class="wp-block-embed__wrapper">
```

https://www.clientssite.com/their-blog-post/

Can you point me in the right direction? Thx

Comment: [آموزش robot.txt](https://betacup.net/%D8%AA%D8%B1%D9%81%D9%86%D8%AF-%D8%AA%D9%86%D8%B8%DB%8C%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%AD%D8%B1%D9%81%D9%87-%D8%A7%DB%8C-robot-txt-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%B3%D8%A6%D9%88-%D8%B3%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AA-%D9%88/%D8%A7%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1-%D9%81%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%88%D8%B1%DB%8C/%D8%B7%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AD%DB%8C-%D8%B3%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AA-%D9%88-%D8%B3%D8%A6%D9%88/ you can use some tricks in robot.txt to do that)

Comment: @M.RMortezaei answers need to be self contained, they can't be links, keep in mind they need to be in english too

Answer (score 0):

If you have used anchor tag manually than in post editor switch to html editor, now add rel="nofollow" in anchor tag like this :

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" rel="nofollow" >Click me text</a>
```